# Java - protected access modifier

Tags: java, inheritance, protected

I have these classes:

```
package abc;

public class A {

    public int publicInt;
    private int privateInt;
    protected int protectedInt;
    int defaultInt;

    public void test() {
        publicInt = 0;
        privateInt = 0;
        protectedInt = 0;
        defaultInt = 0;
    }

}
```

"A" contains attributes of all four access modifiers. These other classes extend "A" or create instances and try to access attributes.

```
package de;

public class D {

    public void test() {
        E e = new E();
        e.publicInt = 0;
        e.privateInt = 0; // error, cannot access
        e.protectedInt = 0; // error, cannot access
        e.defaultInt = 0; // error, cannot access
    }

}

package de;

import abc.A;

public class E extends A {

    public void test() {
        publicInt = 0;
        privateInt = 0; // error, cannot access
        protectedInt = 0; // ok
        defaultInt = 0; // error, cannot access
    }

}

package abc;

import de.E;

public class C {

    public void test() {
        E e = new E();
        e.publicInt = 0;
        e.privateInt = 0; // error, cannot access
        e.protectedInt = 0; // ok, but why?
        e.defaultInt = 0; // error, cannot access
    }

}
```

Everything is ok, except I do not understand, why in class C, I can access e.protectedInt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a code illustration would help here to understand better.

Add a protected member in Class E

```
public class E extends A {
    protected int protectedIntE;
    ...
```

Now, try accessing it in Class C

```
e.protectedInt = 0; // ok, but why?
e.protectedIntE = 0; // error, exactly as you expected
```

So, the thing to note here is that although you accessed `protectedInt` through an instance of `E` it actually belongs to Class A and was just inherited by Class E through inheritance. An actual (non inherited) protected member of Class E is still not accessible like you expected.

Now, since Class A and Class C are in the same package and protected access basically works as a superset of package (by including sub-class access as well) compiler had nothing to complain here.

Answer (score 1):

Because `C` is in the same package as `A` (package `abc`), and the `protected` modifier in Java includes access within the same package.

Answer (score 0):

[Acces Control](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Follow the link, you get to the java documentation, explanes the modifier accessibalities.

`protected` classes, function, etc. are visible for your current class, package and subpackages. Also visible inside subclasses of your class.